# Haskell: Design pattern: classes or pass functions

Tags: design-patterns, haskell

Lets say I have a function which takes some input structure and returns some output structure (which may be related to but different to the input structure).

I don't want to enforce these input/output structures to a particular type, I just want to ensure they have a few behaviors that I need.

Should I?

a) Define a class which has the appropriate extraction methods and force the input data to be an instance of that class? **OR**
b) Have the function accept another parameter which is function(s) that define how one extracts data.

Also I have the same question for the output structures (except this time the required functionality is mutation)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever you have to choose between explicit function arguments and type classes you should ask yourself this most important question:  Are the functions specific to the type or to the application?  An example of the former is `sort`, and an example of the latter is `map`.

Passing functions is always more flexible, but it may be overkill for your situation and cause unnecessary code bloat.  Type classes on the other hand result in much smaller code, but they are also less flexible.

Without further information it's not possible to give a more precise answer here.

Comment: Also, passing functions give you the flexibility of different behaviors for different values of the same type. Type classes will enforce a single behavior for all values of the same type. I don't see a way to define `map` using only type classes (i.e. removing the function argument).

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

The advantage of a type class is that you don't have to explicitly pass around the functions to any helper functions. So, if you have more than two functions or if you're expecting a lot of functions to work with the same basic transformation functions, a type class is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

"I just want to ensure they have a few behaviors that I need." – this pretty much describes what typeclasses are for, I'd go with that. Not sure about the output structure though, I *think* a function has to return a specific type, you can't return one of several types even if they are instances of the same typeclass.

Comment: `fromInteger` seems to return a type that isn't entirely dependent on it's inputs.

Comment: @Clinton Looking at the Hugs source for Prelude, this is because `fromInteger` is an operation of the `Num` typeclass. You'd have to create a separate function implementing this operation for every output type.

Answer (score 0):

A type class provides a **unique** mapping of types to functions. Therefore you should ask whether you always need the same functions for a type. *For example*, if you pass a vector to a function and your function needs a norm for the vector, it is usually not a good idea to use type classes since there are many useful norms. In such a case a function parameter is preferable.